# Assigning same row numbers to repeating values in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a similar code like below, this was posted by someone else - but, I have an exact same problem, I need row numbers to repeat across repeating invoice numbers.

I am new to R so I what ever I tried doesn't seem to work as intended.

```
Sl  invoice
1   A001
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
3   A003
3   A003
4   A004
4   A004
4   A004
4   A004
5   A007
5   A007
```

Comment: If `Sl` is your expected output you can do `df$Sl <- match(df$invoice, unique(df$invoice))`

Comment: You can also use: `N <- rle(df$invoice)$lengths; rep(seq_along(N), N)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak and Jilber, that worked.